# Форматирование строк при помощи табуляции

Tags: c#, консоль

У меня есть текстовый файл, который содержит в себе некоторые данные. Я сделал так, чтобы оттуда забирались только нужные мне строчки, но я не совсем понимаю, как из них мне составить табличку при помощи табуляции примерно следующего содержания:

```
      MassaSr| Time | Temp
        50.3 | 1    | 20*C
       122.1 | 1    | 20*C
```

Сам код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
using System.IO;
 
namespace StreamReaderDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string docpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            Console.WriteLine("Input your txt-file name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(docpath + @"\" + name + ".txt");
 
            string s;
            string t;
            string y;
 
            while (sr.EndOfStream != true)
            {
                s = sr.ReadLine();
                t = sr.ReadLine();
                y = sr.ReadLine();
                if (s.StartsWith("MassaSr:") || t.StartsWith("Time:") || y.StartsWith("Temp:"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    Console.WriteLine(t);
                    Console.WriteLine(y);
                }
            }
 
            sr.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Ссылка на файлик со строками:
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/pE1WPgTc7VpypA

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Никак, табуляция вам тут не поможет.

Comment: А как-то по-другому составить "таблицу" можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Табуляция вам не сильно поможет, ведь у вас сложное выравнивание. Проще не пытаться использовать табуляцию, а подсчитать нужное количество пробелов. Для этого, однако, понадобится как минимум *два* прохода по данным: подсчёт максимальной ширины и сам вывод.

Кешировать ли данные в памяти, чтобы не читать файл дважды, и как именно вытаскивать данные из файла, решать вам. У меня получился такой пример форматирования:

```cs
string headerMassaSr = "MassaSr", headerTime = "Time", headerTemp = "Temp";
int maxMassaSrWidth = headerMassaSr.Length, maxTimeWidth = headerTime.Length, maxTempWidth = headerTemp.Length;
foreach (var item in GetEntries())
{
    maxMassaSrWidth = Math.Max(maxMassaSrWidth, item.MassaSr.Length);
    maxTimeWidth = Math.Max(maxTimeWidth, item.Time.Length);
    maxTempWidth = Math.Max(maxTempWidth, item.Temp.Length);
}

Console.WriteLine($"| {headerMassaSr.PadLeft(maxMassaSrWidth)} | {headerTime.PadRight(maxTimeWidth)} | {headerTemp.PadLeft(maxTempWidth)} |");
Console.WriteLine($"|-{new string('-', maxMassaSrWidth)}-|-{new string('-', maxTimeWidth)}-|-{new string('-', maxTempWidth)}-|");
foreach (var item in GetEntries())
    Console.WriteLine($"| {item.MassaSr.PadLeft(maxMassaSrWidth)} | {item.Time.PadRight(maxTimeWidth)} | {item.Temp.PadLeft(maxTempWidth)} |");
```

с определением

```cs
record Entry(string MassaSr, string Time, string Temp);

IEnumerable<Entry> GetEntries()
{
    // тут или читайте и разбирайте файл, или возвращайте
    // закешированную копию, как вам кажется правильным
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
| MassaSr | Time |  Temp |
|---------|------|-------|
|    50.3 | 1    |  1 *C |
|   122.1 | 1    | 20 *C |
|   409.0 | 15   | 21 *C |
```